# Flutter changing a color of marker on user onTap

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to know how can I change the color of the marker in flutter once a user click(onTap) on the marker

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that the class you are in extends a `StatefulWidget` because that is how the class knows to rerender and show something new when something changes.

Next let's say you want to go from a blue marker to a red, you need to declare a state variable:

```
final bool _showBlue = true;
```

Then, where you set the color of the marker you can do this:

```
color: _showBlue ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
```

Meaning that the color will be blue if _showBlue is true, otherwise it will be red.

Then your onTap will change the state of _showBlue to false to make sure that in the rerender the color will be shown as red:

```
onTap: () {
  setState(() {
    _showBlue = false;
  });
}
```